# I have random challenges and random answers, but i want the random challenges bound to the right answer

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a project for my school. I need to make challenges, if you press the button you get a random challenge, but you also get a random answer. I want to bound the challenge to the right answer. I don't know how to do it with index, so if anyone can show me an example how to do it, I would appreciate it.

I have asked my teachers, and searched but couldn't find anything.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

theWindow = Tk()
theWindow.geometry('500x500')
theWindow.title('Challenges')
Label(theWindow, text='Press the button below to generate random challenges', bg= 'grey', fg='white').pack()

challenges = ['You are going through Russia. Do you have the item winterjacket?\n \n Option 1: Yes \n Option 2: No',
          'A thief grabs your bag with items: What are you going to do?\n\n 
Option 1: Not chasing the thief \n Option 2: Chasing the thief',
          'You don’t have money for food anymore:\n You found a job for a week. \n Are you going to take the job?:\n\n Option 1: Yes, take the job \n 
Option 2: No, you don"t take the job',
          'You walk along a grave and hear a sound: \n What are you going to do?: \n \n Option 1: You run away \n Option 2: You take a look',
          'You won an helicopter flight and you’re in an helicopter right now. \n The helicopter starts to fall down. \n What are you going to do?: \n \n Option 1: Grab a parachute and jump out of the helicopter \n Option 2: Stay in the helicopter',
          'You see an old lady carrying an heavy bag. \n What are you going to do?: \n \n Option 1: Walk away \n Option 2: Help the old lady']

Outcome = ['+10 HP','+10 HP','+10 HP','+10 HP','+10 HP','+10 HP','+10 HP','+10 HP and skip 1 turn', '+20 HP','+20 HP',
           '+20 HP','+20 HP', '+30 HP','+30 HP','+30 HP', '+40 HP', '+10 HP + 1 item','+10 HP + 1 item','+10 HP + 1 item',
           '+20 HP + 1 item','+20 HP + 1 item', '+20 HP + 2 item', 'Back to 100 HP', 'Nothing happens',
          '-10 HP','-10 HP','-10 HP','-10 HP', '-20 HP','-20 HP','-20 HP','-20 HP','-20 HP',
          '-20 HP', '-30 HP', 'Lose all HP', '-40 HP', '-50 HP', 'Lose all items', 'Lose all items', 'Skip 1 turn', '-20 HP and skip 1 turn',
          'You have to throw the dice: if you get 1, 3 or 5 you can get an item. If you throw 2, 4 or 6 you will get -10 HP damage.',
          'Nothing happens']

def challenges_button():
    challenge = Label(theWindow, text=random.choice(challenges))
    challenge.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)

def answers():
    answer = Label(theWindow, text= random.choice(Outcome))
    answer.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)

def answers1():
    answer1 = Label(theWindow, text= random.choice(Outcome))
    answer1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)    

#The buttons
generate_button = Button(theWindow, text='Generate Challenge', height=3, 
width=20, command=challenges_button, bg='black', fg='white')
generate_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=CENTER)

button_1_Button = Button(theWindow, text='Option 1', height=1, width=20, 
command=answers, bg='black', fg='white')
button_1_Button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor=CENTER)

button_2_Button = Button(theWindow, text='Option 2', height=1, width=20, 
command=answers1, bg='black', fg='white')
button_2_Button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)
```

Expected: You press generate challenge and you get the right answer. The actual result now is that you get a challenge but random answer, so the answer isn't correct.

Comment: Where is the correct answers defined in the code? Only god knows the correct answer if there's no way to tell what the correct answer is by code.

Comment: Yes that is what i want to know. How can i connect the answer to the challenge. The outcomes are 'the answers', but it isnt good. I have 30/40 challenges, so also 30/40 answers thats why there are so many outcomes and what i want is to bound 2 outcomes to 1 challenge.

Comment: You can simply group the challenge and corresponding answer into a list.  Then group all these challenge and answer pairs into another list.

Comment: My teacher also suggested that, but i dont know how do to that. Can you maybe make 1 list so i can make the rest, because im a beginner and dont know how do to it correctly.

Comment: I have only 6 questions copy pasted othwerise it would be too long. But every time 2 outcome 'answers' will be bound to 1 question. How can i bound 2 outcome answers to 1 question?

Comment: So, you are saying, say, the 4th question will have 6th and 7th element of `Outcome` list as the answers?

Comment: Yes, thats true. How can i do that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be element 7 and 8 with index 6 and 7? don't mean to nitpick, just want to make sure i understood this right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, generate a random index in `challenges` list. And using that index, you can configure the `text` of the *Label* using the *challenge* present at that index in the `challenges` list. Corresponding to that, you also know the two answers to it are the `2i`'th and `2i+1`'th element in the `Outcome` list.

There are a few problems with your code as well. If you click on the `Generate` button multiple times, they will start overlapping. So I have removed that from the function.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

theWindow = tk.Tk()
theWindow.title('Challenges')
tk.Label(theWindow, text='Press the button below to generate random challenges', bg= 'grey', fg='white').grid(row=0)

index = None

challenges = ['Q1) You are going through Russia. Do you have the item winterjacket?\n \n Option 1: Yes \n Option 2: No',
          'Q2) A thief grabs your bag with items: What are you going to do?\n\n Option 1: Not chasing the thief \n Option 2: Chasing the thief',
          'Q3) You don’t have money for food anymore:\n You found a job for a week. \n Are you going to take the job?:\n\n Option 1: Yes, take the job \n Option 2: No, you don"t take the job',
          'Q4) You walk along a grave and hear a sound: \n What are you going to do?: \n \n Option 1: You run away \n Option 2: You take a look',
          'Q5) You won an helicopter flight and you’re in an helicopter right now. \n The helicopter starts to fall down. \n What are you going to do?: \n \n Option 1: Grab a parachute and jump out of the helicopter \n Option 2: Stay in the helicopter',
          'Q6) You see an old lady carrying an heavy bag. \n What are you going to do?: \n \n Option 1: Walk away \n Option 2: Help the old lady']

Outcome = ['q1 a1', 'q1 a2', 'q2 a1', 'q2 a2', 'q3 a1', 'q3 a2', 'q4 a1', 'q4 a2', 'q5 a1', 'q5 a2', 'q6 a1', 'q6 a2']

challenge = tk.Label(theWindow)
challenge.grid(row=2)

answer = tk.Label(theWindow)
answer.grid(row=5)

def challenges_button():
    global index
    index = random.choice(range(len(challenges)))
    answer.configure(text="")
    challenge.configure(text=challenges[index])

def answers():
    global index
    answer.configure(text=Outcome[2*index])

def answers1():
    global index
    answer.configure(text=Outcome[2*index+1])

#The buttons
generate_button = tk.Button(theWindow, text='Generate Challenge', height=3, width=20, command=challenges_button, bg='black', fg='white')
generate_button.grid(row=1)

button_1_Button = tk.Button(theWindow, text='Option 1', height=1, width=20, command=answers, bg='black', fg='white')
button_1_Button.grid(row=3)

button_2_Button = tk.Button(theWindow, text='Option 2', height=1, width=20, command=answers1, bg='black', fg='white')
button_2_Button.grid(row=4)

theWindow.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thank you very much sir, this one worked also for me. Im glad that you helped me also

Answer (score 1):

This is a little workaround, starting from the point where you're at now. As there are exactly 2 outcomes for every question, what i would suggest first of all is to group all "right answers" for every challenge into sublists, like this (made up these answers, but you get the point):

```
new_outcome = [['+10 HP', '-10 HP'], ['+20 HP', '+10 HP'], ...]
```

Also, make sure to put these in the right order, so that the first answer pair in the `new_outcome` list belongs to the first challenge in the `challenges` list, and also the answer for option 1 is the first of th two elements.

---

**Quick Edit:** if i get this right from your comment under your original question, your answers are already in the right order. So simply make a list comprehension like this:

```
new_outcome = [[Outcome[2*i], Outcome[2*i + 1]] for i in range(int(len(Outcome) / 2))]
```

to create the desired list of answer pairs.

---

Now, you can create a dictionary (for more info on dictionaries look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys)), use the challenges as keys and group each challenge with the corresponding answers (packed into a list):

```
c_and_a = dict()

for item in challenges:
    c_and_a[item] = new_outcome[challenges.index(item)]

>> c_and_a = {'challenge_1':['+10 HP', '-10 HP'], 'challenge_2':['+20 HP', '+10 HP'], ...}
```

Now, define the button commands as follows. Note that the method i suggest here requires you to define your `challenge` label outside of the function, because all functions need to access it. You can do that at the bottom together with all your other widgets, your functions still have access to it even if defined above it.

```
def challenges_button():
    challenge.config(text=random.choice(list(c_and_a.keys())))
```

`c_and_a` is a dictionary. In python 3.x, which i assume you are using based on your `tkinter` import, `d.keys()`returns an iterator over all keys of a dictionary `d`. Since `random.choice` only works with lists, we first have to convert this iterator into a list via the `list()` command.

Now, you have chosen a challenge, but the user still has to select an answer. You could store your randomly selected key in a variable to use it later for determining the right pair of answers, but i would suggest just reading the `challenge` label again. And finally, define a single answer Label, outside of your functions, to avoid overlapping:

```
def answers():
    chall = challenge.cget('text')  # this will read the challenge label
    answer.config(text=c_and_a[chall][0])  # for option 1

def answers1():
    chall = challenge.cget('text')
    answer.config(text=c_and_a[chall][1])  # for option 2

answer = Label(theWindow)
answer.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)
```

Now you should be good to go!